# Объясните строчку new Runnable и New SwingDemo

Tags: java, объекты

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new SwingDemo();
            }
        });
    }
```

Вопрос, почему new Runnable и new SwingDemo не присваиваются ссылки на экземпляры объектов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Присваивание обычно происходит не экземплярам, а экземпляров. Экземпляры присваиваются переменным или полям, если планируется использовать их в других участках кода. В данном случае код, видимо, такого использования не предполагает.

Comment: То есть, так как за пределами метода main эти объекты не используются, то и ссылочные переменные во время объявления не требуются?

Comment: Они в самом методе main дальше нигде не используются.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо. Если это так, то вопрос наверное исчерпан